# hadoop enviroment is not available until i format the name node and continue always

Tags: hadoop

Iam using single node hadoop cluster in ubuntu 13.10 with hadoop 1.2.1

Always iam having a problem like
whenever i restart my compueter and want to enter into hadoop environment

i login to terminal and type su

i get error like bin/su not in something

i do export /user/bin:/bin

then it works

then after getting into su

when i type hadoop fs -ls 
i get error like trying 1..2...

### lastly it failes

```
user@ubuntu1310:~$ su
Command 'su' is available in '/bin/su'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
su: command not found
user@ubuntu1310:~$ export PATH=/user/bin:bin
user@ubuntu1310:~$ su
Command 'su' is available in '/bin/su'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
su: command not found
user@ubuntu1310:~$ su
Command 'su' is available in '/bin/su'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
su: command not found
user@ubuntu1310:~$ export PATH=/usr/bin:bin
user@ubuntu1310:~$ su
Command 'su' is available in '/bin/su'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
su: command not found
user@ubuntu1310:~$ export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
user@ubuntu1310:~$ su
Password: 
root@ubuntu1310:/home/user# start-all.sh
starting namenode, logging to /usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-root-namenode-ubuntu1310.out
root@localhost's password: 
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-root-datanode-ubuntu1310.out
root@localhost's password: 
localhost: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-root-secondarynamenode-ubuntu1310.out
starting jobtracker, logging to /usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-root-jobtracker-ubuntu1310.out
root@localhost's password: 
localhost: starting tasktracker, logging to /usr/lib/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-root-tasktracker-ubuntu1310.out
root@ubuntu1310:/home/user# hadoop fs -ls
14/01/09 05:46:56 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/01/09 05:46:57 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/01/09 05:46:58 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/01/09 05:46:59 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/01/09 05:47:00 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/01/09 05:47:01 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/01/09 05:47:02 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/01/09 05:47:03 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/01/09 05:47:04 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/01/09 05:47:05 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
ls: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
root@ubuntu1310:/home/user# hadoop fs -ls
14/01/09 05:54:58 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/01/09 05:54:59 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/01/09 05:55:00 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/01/09 05:55:01 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/01/09 05:55:02 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/01/09 05:55:03 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/01/09 05:55:04 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/01/09 05:55:05 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/01/09 05:55:06 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/01/09 05:55:07 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
ls: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
root@ubuntu1310:/home/user#
```

---

How can i aviod this 2 errors as 
its very hard for me to format namenode always

Comment: Your hadoop client can't connect to NameNode. Do you have NameNode running? Before "formatting" can you check if there is a java process listening on port 8020 (netstat -ntlp | grep 8020)? Can you access the NameNode webpage (http://localhost:50070/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all su has nothing to do with Hadoop. Next, you are getting these errors probably because you have not specified **hadoop.tmp.dir** property in your **core-site.xml**. The value of this property defaults to **/tmp** which gets emptied at each restart. Thus you loose all the HDFS metadata+data and have to reformat it.

It is always a good practice to add this property. Also, it is advisable to add **dfs.name.dir** and **dfs.data.dir** properties in your **hdfs-site.xml** files.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you have not set the password less login while installing hadoop it is recommended to set password less log in

for proper installation guide you can refer

http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/